# Set a Javascript function to be all the code in another .js file

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a file `doSomething.js` that contains some code that needs to be run both from the command line (eg: `node doSomething.js`) and also from a nodejs-based queue worker

**queueWorker.js**

```
var worker = client.worker(['example']);

worker.register({
    doSomething: function (params, callback) {
        // run the code contained in doSomething.js
    }
});

worker.start();
```

**doSomething.js**

```
console.log('Hello world')
```

**Question:** Is there a way to let the main code remain in `doSomething.js` and just include a reference to `doSomething.js` in `queueWorker.js`? I dont want to have 2 copies of the same code in 2 different files.

Comment: looks like you are searching for [requirejs](http://requirejs.org/)?

Comment: If the both files are referred on a HTML page with a proper sequence then this can be achieved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So if I understand you correctly you've some code in a project that you want to be used by a command-line node script and by a worker. You don't mention how you deploy this code, so I'm going to assume that the stuff running the worker is the same codebase as the command line.

In which case I would assume that one solution is to make your `doSomething.js` use the [standard NodeJS module system](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html), i.e. something like

**doSomething.js**

```
module.exports = function() {
  console.log('Hello, world');
}
```

**queueWorker.js**

Your worker would become something like:

```
var worker = client.worker(['example']);
var doSomething = require('path/to/doSomething');
worker.register({
    doSomething: function (params, callback) {
        doSomething();
    }
});

worker.start();
```

**doSomethingCli.js**

Your command line script would be a totally separate script to the above (assuming that's okay), looking something similar to the worker:

```
var doSomething = require('path/to/doSomething');
doSomething();
```

While you stated you wanted to have `doSomething.js` callable from the command line that isn't a great solution - you'll find yourself starting to put cli stuff into doSomething.js which will break your queue worker. Keep the common code separate.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are using node for both cases.

**queueWorker.js**

```
var doSomething = require('./doSomething');
var worker = client.worker(['example']);

worker.register({
    doSomething: function (params, callback) {
       doSomething(params, callback);
    }
});

worker.start();
```

**doSomething.js**

```
module.exports = functionv(params, callback) {
 console.log('Hello world');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Javascript is a dynamic language and it's always possible to `eval` a string containing code. For example you can do this

```
// file1.js -------------------------

function foo() {
    console.log("Hello, world.");
}

// file2.js -------------------------

eval(require('fs').readFileSync("file1.js", "utf-8"));
foo();
```

Of course `node.js` contains a much better approach if the code is indeed static and you just want to share it between different projects (the idea of modules).